# Foreach code works for %do% but not for %dopar%

Tags: r, foreach

This works normally on my computer:

```
registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(2, type = "SOCK"))

foreach(i = 1:M,.combine = "c") %dopar% {

  sum(rnorm(M))
  }
```

So I can say that I can run parallelized code on this computer, right?

Ok. I have a piece of code that I wish to run on parallel with *foreach*. It runs perfectly when it's written with %do%, but doesn't work properly when I change it to %dopar%. (PS: I have already initialized the cluster with `registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(2, type = "SOCK"))` in the same way as before.)

My main interest in the code is getting the vector *u.varpred*. I get it nicely with %do%, but when I run it with %dopar%, the vector comes as a NULL.

Here is the loop with the code that's needed to run it all properly. It uses functions in the *geoR* package.

```
#you can pretty much ignore all this, it's just preparation for the loop
N=20
NN=10 

set.seed(111);
datap <- grf(N, cov.pars=c(20, 5),nug=1) 

grid.o <- expand.grid(seq(0, 1, l=100), seq(0, 1, l=100))
grid.c <- expand.grid(seq(0, 1, l=NN), seq(0,1, l=NN)) 

beta1=mean(datap$data)
emv<- likfit(datap, ini=c(10,0.4), nug=1) 
krieging <- krige.conv(datap, loc=grid.o,
                       krige=krige.control(type.krige="SK", trend.d="cte",
                                           beta =beta1, cov.pars=emv$cov.pars))



names(grid.c) = names(as.data.frame(datap$coords))
list.geodatas<-list()
valores<-c(datap$data,0)
list.dataframes<-list()

list.krigings<-list(); i=0; u.varpred=NULL;

#here is the foreach code
t<-proc.time()
foreach(i=1:length(grid.c[,1]), .packages='geoR') %do% {
  list.dataframes[[i]] <- rbind(datap$coords,grid.c[i,]);
  list.geodatas[[i]] <- as.geodata(data.frame(cbind(list.dataframes[[i]],valores)))
  list.krigings[[i]] <- krige.conv(list.geodatas[[i]], loc=grid.o,
                                   krige=krige.control(type.krige="SK", trend.d="cte",
                                                       beta =beta1, cov.pars=emv$cov.pars));
  u.varpred[i] <- mean(krieging$krige.var - list.krigings[[i]]$krige.var)
  list.dataframes[[i]]<-0 #i dont need those objects anymore but since they
  # are lists i dont want to put <-NULL as it'll ruin their ordering
  list.krigings[[i]]<- 0 
  list.geodatas[[i]] <-0
}
t<-proc.time()-t
t
```

You can check that this runs nicely (provided you have the following packages: *geoR*, *foreach* and *doSNOW*). But once I use `registerDoSNOW(......)` and `%dopar%`, *u.varpred* comes as a NULL.

Could you guys please try to see if I made a mistake in the foreach statement/process or if it's just the code that can't be parallel? (I thought it could, because any given iteration does not deppend on any of the iterations before it..)

I am sorry both the code and this question are so long. Thanks in advance for taking the time to read it.

Answer (score 3):

My friend helped me directly. Here is a way it works:

```
    u.varpred <- foreach(i = 1:length(grid.c[,1]), .packages = 'geoR', .combine = "c") %dopar% {
  list.dataframes[[i]] <- rbind(datap$coords,grid.c[i,]);
  list.geodatas[[i]] <- as.geodata(data.frame(cbind(list.dataframes[[i]],valores)));
  list.krigings[[i]] <- krige.conv(list.geodatas[[i]], loc = grid.o,
                        krige = krige.control(type.krige = "SK", trend.d = "cte",
                        beta = beta1, cov.pars = emv$cov.pars));
  u.varpred <- mean(krieging$krige.var - list.krigings[[i]]$krige.var);
  list.dataframes[[i]] <- 0; 
  list.krigings[[i]] <- 0;
  list.geodatas[[i]] <- 0;
  u.varpred #this makes the results go into u.varpred
}
```

He gave me an example on why this works:

```
a <- NULL
foreach(i = 1:10) %dopar% {
  a <- 5
}
print(a)
# a is still NULL

a <- NULL
a <- foreach(i = 1:10) %dopar% {
  a <- 5
  a
}
print(a)
#now it works
```

Hope this helps anyone.